# Categorical data to binary, Python

Tags: python, deep-learning

in my data I have a variable on the categorical X axis that is Renewed or New, I want to change it to binary 1 or 0, how can it be done?
I tried this code but I can't

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

the transformation I achieve are random numbers

Comment: LabelEncoder provides category to every different value. To change it to binary, your data should have only 2 types of categorical values. Otherwise there is no way

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it depends on the cardinality of your column "New" or "Renewed". That means, how much distinct classes of possible values can appear there. In order for LabelEncoder to encode it to Binary column, cardinality must be 2.

**In that case, LabelEncoder would assign value 0 to first class, and value 1 to second class.**

If the cardinality is not 2 (so possible values in the column are for example: Paris, Tokio, Berlin; then the easiest approach is a manual one.

```
df["New"] = df["New"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in ["Paris","Berlin"] else 0)
```

*Here, we are applying lambda function to datacolumn df["New"]. So, we are applying that functions to every row in that column. Assigning 1 if value in that row is Paris or Berlin, otherwise 0*

The reason why you get random numbers is probably because cardinality of your column is not 2, meaning that LabelEncoder would assign unique number to every distinct class of possible values.